# Do I need to add 'sudo' for mysqldump command, for the MySql backup script

Tags: ubuntu, shell-scripting

I am trying to write mysql backup script for cron.
Using Ubuntu server.

Current code is as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
mysqldump -u root --all-databases > /root/all_databases_backup-`date +%A`.sql
```

Do I need to add 'sudo' before mysqldump, like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mysqldump -u root --all-databases > /root/all_databases_backup-`date +%A`.sql
```

The reason I ask is because when I run mysql/mysqldump in shell, it always says Permission denied. I need to sudo to go thru.

So does the command in script also require sudo ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`mysqldump` will need a password for the mysql user *root*.  If you don't supply that password it won't work, `sudo` or no `sudo`.

`mysqldump` can look at your `.my.cnf` file to get the password, and it'll get that from the user **runing** the `mysqldump` command.  So, if the Linux *root* user has a .my.cnf configured with a password in it, then yes, `sudo` will help.  However, if the mysql *root* user has a password and it's not configured in any `.my.cnf`'s then `sudo` won't help.

You could add the mysql *root* user and password to your own user's `.my.cnf` and then you don't need `sudo` either, but that's a security risk.

As the other answers point out as well, you might need `sudo` to write the output somewhere that *root* (Linux, not mysql) owns.

Lastly, you don't tell us which user is executing the script, if it's in *root*'s crontab (for example), then `sudo` will not be necessary, although you may still need a `.my.cnf` to provide the password.

If your mysql *root* user has no password set, then the only issue is writing the output, in which case `sudo` is required if you don't run the script as *root*.

If you run the script as root (for example, as a script in `/etc/cron.daily`) then you should not use sudo within the script, irrespective of all the above comments.

Comment: (1) I login as a normal user (not root), (2) I create the script as $ sudo  nano /etc/cron.daily/mysqlbackup .   (3) and chmod a+x  to it. (4)  And I also add root pass to /root/my.con.   =>  in this case, do I still need sudo in that script?

Comment: The script is running as root.  So no, you don't need sudo.  sudo allows you to run commands as if you were another user, usually root (but not always).  If you are root, you don't need sudo.  /etc/cron.daily/scripts run as root.

Answer (score 4):

The `mysqldump` command does not require `sudo`, but saving the dump file under `/root` folder requires root privileges. So, you need to run your script using `sudo`.

You can also note that running the following command:

```
sudo mysqldump -u root --all-databases > /root/all_databases_backup-`date +%A`.sql
```

will give your *permission denied* error. This is because the output redirection is still not running as root, but only the dump part.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you need sudo to write to the /root/ folder. If you can dump the database to any other folder with correct permissions (or change permissions on /root - not recommended), you can use it without sudo.